# Eclipse get hang after some time with error of java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

I am using Eclipse Juno for android development purpose.

I am working on the project contain 4-5 library in it. Do know what is the reason but after several use of that same project My Eclipse get hang. Another thing is it only get hang while i am trying to run the app from eclipse.

After that my Eclipse get stop working and in Not Responding condition. When i click on that, I got below message by closing of Eclipse.
Message:
[image]

I don't know what is the reason for causing of this. Please help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because of a corrupted workspace. For, solution refer

[this](http://spacetech.dk/eclipse-failed-java-was-started-but-returned-exit-code-805306369.html)

> The error was due to a corrupt workspace. As I disable the workspace check in the startup I couldn’t select another workspace since Eclipse wouldn’t start. Rename the workspace e.g. to “workspace1″. Eclipse will start and create a new uncorrupted workspace and work without any problems. Afterwards you can import your project into your new workspace and in the end remove the old corrupted workspace.

So, you have to create a new workspace

Comment: Thanks for answer. And You mean i have to create new Workspace and then move all project to that new WorkSpace? If this is the case then can you please tell me the simplest way to import all the project from old workspace to new one?

Answer (score 2):

The most common reason I've seen Eclipse crash is due to running out of memory. Try editing the eclipse.ini file in your Eclipse installation directory, and changing the part where it says -Xmx512m to -Xmx1g (or 2g, if you have a lot of free memory on your system). You can also increase -Xms40m to -Xms512m or similar to make Eclipse start with more allocated memory initially.

Answer (score 0):

Close your project from eclipse and try again. If it doesn't work, copy your projects into a new workspace and open them from there